# Unable to build android app - EPERM: operation not permitted Error

Tags: android-studio, react-native, npm

I have a project work with react native and android studio. In in this project it has a readme file. Readme files has the following steps to build the app.

- npm install
- npm start
- Open xcode or android studio build native project

When I build it using Android studio, the build was successful. But, the app was not working. It just appear few seconds and get closed with the following error message in the command prompt.

> events.js:177
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: EPERM:  operation not permitted, lstat
>   'C:\Users\ToraraBD\Documents\templatephoto\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\devKernelDebug\processDevKernelDebugResources\r\android\arch\lifecycle\viewmodel\R.java'
>
> Emitted 'error' event at:
>
> at NodeWatcher. (C:\Users\ToraraBD\Documents\templatephoto\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:306:14)
>
> at C:\Users\ToraraBD\Documents\templatephoto\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
>
> at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21) {   errno: -4048,   code: 'EPERM',   syscall: 'lstat',   path:
>   'C:\Users\ToraraBD\Documents\templatephoto\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\devKernelDebug\processDevKernelDebugResources\r\android\arch\lifecycle\viewmodel\R.java'
>   }

What is this error ? and how can i fix it ?